# Image not showing on microdata code

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

Im trying to get this rich snipnet going, so far no errors but no image shown:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" style="display: none;">
    <span itemprop="name">Canon EOS 5D (prove)</span>
    <span itemprop="description"><p>Canon's press material for the <strong>EOS 5D</strong> states that it 'defines (a) new D-SLR category', while we're not typically too concerned with marketing talk this particular statement is clearly pretty accurate. The EOS 5D is unlike any previous digital SLR in that it combines a full-frame (35 mm sized) high resolution sensor (12.8 megapixels) with a relatively compact body (slightly larger than the <strong>EOS 20D</strong>, although in your hand it feels noticeably 'chunkier').</p>
</span>

    <img itemprop="image" src="http://wonna.it/image/cache/data/demo/canon_eos_5d_2-74x74.jpg"/>

   <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">3</span>
        <span itemprop="reviewCount">3 recensioni</span>,
    </div>

</div>
```

This is how I check there is no image: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwonna.it%2Fcamera-eos-canon&html=

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting things mixed up.

Microdata is designed to describe your website so software can interpret your page and have a much better understanding of what you are publishing to the world.

**This standard is not designed about how you look on Google!**

Google also uses this standard (and many more techniques) to decide how *they* want to represent your site in *their* results.
Because you start to describe a product with an image *won't force them* to display it in their result.